# How to concat two (IO) Strings in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, concatenation

I know this sound very simple, but I failed to combine two strings into a new one.

The IO String "a" from a gtk entry is fetched by

```
      a <- (entryGetText text_field)
```

The goal is to combine it like:

newstring = "Text: "+a

Any ideas to accomplish that?
Thanks!

Comment: `newstring <- fmap ("Text: " ++) $ entryGetText text_field`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using string concatenation:

```
 do a <- entryGetText text_field
    let b = "Text:" ++ a
    return b
```

More simply:

```
 do a <- entryGetText text_field
    return $ "Text:" ++ a
```

You can play games too:

```
 ("Text:" ++) <$> (entryGetText text_field)
```

Comment: To expand on that last line of code: `<$>` is equivalent to `\`fmap\`` as infix operator. So what this does is that it takes the value out of the IO Monad `(entryGetText text_field)` and applies `("Text:" ++)` to it.

Answer (score 14):

I believe that in Haskell, the string concatenation operator is `++`.

Comment: No! That is concatenation of lists.

Comment: @Lindhea The `String` type is just a `List` of `Char`s, so `++` will also work on `String`s. For example, `"has" ++ "kell"` returns `"haskell"`.

Answer (score 6):

The very moment you use the assignment operator `x <- expr` with `expr :: m a` and `m` being some monad, `x` is not an `m a` but rather an `a`. In your case, the variable `a` has type `String` and not `IO String`, so you can concatenate it as you would do in pure code, e.g. `"hello world " ++ a`.